# Duplicate text in <p:messages> summary and detail

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, message, growlnotify

When the email address is invalid the message displayed is "Invalid email.Invalid email.". I know that the message has two parts: summary and a details. I need both of these, but I want to have different info in each. How can I change the message to display "Invalid email:  Please enter a valid email address" instead?

```
<p:messages showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <h:outputText value="#{label.email}: *" />
    <p:inputText required="true" value="#{userWizard.emailAddress}"
        validatorMessage="#{label.invalidEmail}" label="#{label.email}">
        <f:validateRegex pattern="^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$">
        </f:validateRegex>
    </p:inputText>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: If I change the validatorMessage to "Invalid email: Please enter a valid email email address" this text appears twice in the message displayed: Invalid email: Please enter a valid email addressInvalid email: Please enter a valid email address.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not possible with `validatorMessage` (neither `converterMessage` nor `requiredMessage`). The value will be used as *both* the summary and the detail.

You'd need to homegrow a custom validator instead wherein you can construct the `FacesMessage` with the both parts *yourself*. Assuming that you've next to the `label.email` also a `label.email_detail` which represents the message detail, then it should look something like this:

```
@FacesValidator("emailValidator")
public class EmailValidator implements Validator {

    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("([^.@]+)(\\.[^.@]+)*@([^.@]+\\.)+([^.@]+)");

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        if (value == null || ((String) value).isEmpty()) {
            return; // Let required="true" handle.
        }

        if (!PATTERN.matcher((String) value).matches()) {
            String summary = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{label.email}", String.class);
            String detail = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{label.email_detail}", String.class);
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, summary, detail));
        }
    }

}
```

*(note that I adapted the email regexp for better preparation on world domination; non-latin characters like Chinese, Hebrew, Cyrillic, etc are namely allowed in domain names and thus also email addresses since the new [IANA decision in 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name))*

which is then to be used as

```html
<p:inputText ... validator="emailValidator" />
```

Comment: I have tested your solution and it works. I have changed two parts. The `required=true` has also the same problem as the `validatorMessage`(it displays the same text twice), so I have handled the empty string value validation with the same email regex. `String` class has a `matches` method and I have used that method instead of the `Pattern` class.

Comment: You're welcome. The `required="true"` would only have that problem when its summary and detail are exactly the same. You should then alter `javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED` and `javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED_DETAIL` properties of JSF `<message-bundle>`. See also http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/customize-validation-error-message-in-jsf-2-0/

Comment: As to the `Pattern` approach, I'm perfectly aware about `String#matches()`, but it recompiles the pattern everytime which is a quite expensive job.  Compiling it once as constant and then reusing it is much faster. It's just a performance improvement approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will look over your recommendations.

Comment: I would vote ten times for your answer. It helped me a lot. I have run into some troubles recently because of REQUIRED_DETAIL. I think it should be REQUIRED_detail.

Answer (score 5):

According to the documentation here : http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.4/primefaces-p/messages.html

You could do something like that :

```
<p:messages showSummary="true" showDetails="true" />
```

You can also put them apart... for styling :

```
<p:messages showSummary="false" showDetails="true" />
<p:messages showSummary="true" showDetails="false" />
```

But you can't define the two error messages with validatorMessage :

http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.4/primefaces-p/inputText.html

Comment: thank's, i only add  <p:messages showDetail="false" />